# How to show scrollbar even if table data have more width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve vertical and horizontal scroll in table .It working fine but I face one issue . vertical scroll bar is showing to the right of the table I mean when I scroll to the right of the table it showing at the end of the table . I want if table have more td or width I want to show scrollbar. Like when I scrolldown it must show scroll bar.

**code**

```
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 370px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean. Have you tried `table { overflow-x: scroll; }`?

Comment: Actually, I want horizontal and vertical scroll in table . Do you have any example please

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:

You need to wrap it in `div` and set `style="overflow: auto"` to that div

```html
<div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 150px;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Alfreds FutterkisteAlfreds FutterkisteAlfreds FutterkisteAlfreds FutterkisteAlfreds FutterkisteAlfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Maria Anders Maria Anders Maria Anders</td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany Germany </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```